# Struggling with recaptcha v2 and form submission

Tags: php, json, forms, recaptcha

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secretKey = 'MYKEY';
$request = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$recaptchaResponse);

    if(!strstr($request,"false")){
echo '<div class="notification error clearfix"><p><strong>Attention!</strong> You didnt complete the captcha.</p></div>';
exit();
```

Then the rest of the php file mails the form, but its just sending anyway even if you dont complete the recaptcha. Basically if the JSON returns a false I was hoping the it wouldnt send and would display an error

Also here is the form from the page if it helps, Ive probably done something wrong there too...

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="container">

            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-field grid-half">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field grid-half">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <span><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field grid-full">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <span><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></span>
                </div>                  
                <div class="form-field grid-full">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MYKEY"></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-click grid-full">
                <span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" /></span>
            </div>

            <div id="alert" class="grid-full"></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Why use a Captcha at all? At our company we did a study and found that round about 30% of people will simply leave a form with a captcha. Maybe look into the Honeypot Technique coupled with some Good server side validation and techniques like tracking the time it takes a user to complete a form and contents of the textarea for total links in the textarea. If you go this way you will no longer need captchas and your users will be happy. Read this it might help: http://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found that sometimes, depending on the PHP version/config, accessing an object directly won't work, so use `json_decode()`.

```
/* $response object returned from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify via which ever method you use */

$obj = json_decode($response);
if($obj->success == true)
{
    //passes test
}
else
{
    //error handling
}
```

Comment: To be clear,`YOUR_SITE_KEY` should be the "Secret key" *not* the "Site key" and `$captcha` is `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`

Comment: Yes, 'secret key' and 'private key' here are the same thing, it's terminology from v1. It works for me. Doing this using this simple code is much easier than setting up one of the available packages/components.

Answer (score 25):

Using `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` (should you, like me, want `file_get_contents` to be disabled in the server settings)

```
$post_data = "secret=__your_secret_key__&response=".
   $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
   array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 
   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
$googresp = curl_exec($ch);       
$decgoogresp = json_decode($googresp);
curl_close($ch);

if ($decgoogresp->success == true)
    {
    // Success
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is the better answer as recaptcha v2 API documentation states this should be a POST whereas file_get_contents is GET.

Comment: that worked for me. `file_get_contents` doesnt work at all

Answer (score 7):

Paste this snippet before the closing  tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
```

Example :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
    <form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="39"></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
       <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**form.php**

```
<?php

        $email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $email=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==true)            
        {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
?>
```

Sorce :

- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
- http://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

Comment: I found that this solution depends on the PHP version and some configuration (something it's not always possible to be in control of for some shared servers). To remedy, use `$obj =json_decode($response);       if($obj->{'success'}==true)`

Comment: This is actually what I needed: A simple, step by step explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First off, the answers already given here are absolutely adequate.
That being said, I just wanted to include this function that wraps those answers into a slightly more convenient method, that way you can throw them into your function library and pretty much forget about it until google changes something. Enjoy!

```
//Put these two functions into your function library-------
function CaptchaVerify($apiSecret)
{
    //Returns -1 if no captcha response was in post(user did not submit form)
    //Returns 0 if the verification fails
    //Returns 1 if the verification succeeds
    $captcha = isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])? "&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']:'';
    if($captcha != '')
    {
        $verifyUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $apiSecret = "?secret=".$apiSecret;
        $remoteip = "&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents($verifyUrl.$apiSecret.$captcha.$remoteip);
        $obj = json_decode($response);
        return (integer)$obj->success;          
    }
    return -1;
}
function MyCaptchaVerify()
{
    $apiSecret = "PUT YOUR CAPTCHA SECRET HERE";
    return CaptchaVerify($apiSecret);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
//Example usage in your form
switch(MyCaptchaVerify())
{
    case -1:echo "The form has not been submitted yet(First Load).<br>";break;
    case  0:echo "The captcha verification failed.<br>";    break;
    case  1:echo "The captcha verification succeeded.<br>"; break;
}
```

Comment: I improved your solution using Curl and OOP: https://gist.github.com/sentenza/f4f8dcce126ccba93d042ada5eae379b

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the cURL example to the file_get_contents as it gives more options for error logging and such. Some find cURL quite daunting though. For those users Guzzle is a very good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Curl PHP for getting response, you can use the following code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $privatekey = "paste_your_privatekey";
     $responseKey = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
     $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

     /////Curl Start///////
     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=$privatekey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP");

     // Receive server response ...
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
     $response = json_decode($server_output);

     curl_close ($ch);
     /////Curl Close///////

     // Further processing ...
     if ($response->success == "true") {
        Success……..
     }esle{
        Failed…………….
     }
  }
```

Answer (score -6):

```
if (response == true) {
    mail();
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```